# MSBuild - Capture original Property value

Tags: msbuild

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>MyCustomNamespace</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- warn if not default -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetServer) and '$(RootNamespace)' != '$(MSBuildProjectName)'">
    <MyWarnings Include="RootNamespace would be overridden">
      <Info>$(RootNamespace)</Info>
      <Code>MY0001</Code>
    </MyWarnings>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetServer)">
    <RootNamespace>MyServer.$(AssemblyName)</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="ShowMyWarnings" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'@(MyWarnings)' != ''">
    <Warning Text="@(MyWarnings) %(MyWarnings.Info)" Code="%(MyWarnings.Code)"/>
  </Target>
```

It outputs new value

> Warning MY0001 : RootNamespace would be overridden MyServer.MyAssemblyName

But I want property value at the moment of the Item definition

> Warning MY0001 : RootNamespace would be overridden MyCustomNamespace

Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022) doc, it looks like its impossible (properties evaluated before items), maybe there is some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since properties evaluated before items, value should captured during properties evaluation phase (in another property).

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(RootNamespace)' != '$(MSBuildProjectName)'">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OldRootNamespaceValue>$(RootNamespace)</OldRootNamespaceValue>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <MyWarnings Include="RootNamespace would be overridden">
          <Info>$(OldRootNamespaceValue)</Info>
          <Code>MY0001</Code>
        </MyWarnings>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```